# How to configure device to trust root certificate when using a SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: linux, proxy, certificates, socks5-proxy

I am routing a Linux machine through a SOCKS5 proxy. The internet works as expected and I am presented with the proxy's IP when viewing http://whatismyip.com.

However, some sites are reporting that I am experiencing a MITM attack:

> Software is Preventing Firefox From Safely Connecting to This Site
>
> www.mozilla.org is most likely a safe site, but a secure connection
>   could not be established. This issue is caused by DigiCert Global Root
>   CA, which is either software on your computer or your network.
>
> What can you do about it?
>
> www.mozilla.org has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport
>   Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it
>   securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.
>
> If your antivirus software includes a feature that scans encrypted connections (often called “web scanning” or “https scanning”), you can
>   disable that feature. If that doesn’t work, you can remove and
>   reinstall the antivirus software.
>
> - If you are on a corporate network, you can contact your IT department.
> - If you are not familiar with DigiCert Global Root CA, then this could be an attack, and there is nothing you can do to access the
>     site.

```
https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/new/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=support.mozilla.org

Your connection is being intercepted by a TLS proxy. Uninstall it if possible or configure your device to trust its root certificate.

HTTP Strict Transport Security: true
HTTP Public Key Pinning: false

Certificate chain:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How do I alleviate this error so that I can access these sites? Do I need to accept some certificate on my local machine or on the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this off-and-on for a few days (I'm running Fedora 31 beta for a couple weeks) and starting to cause issues with some of the sites I visit.

Since Firefox has it's own list of certificates, I could verify it was not a network issue by pulling up Chrome/Chromium and view the pages.

I was able to un-install then re-install Firefox and that has solved the problem for me.

Comment: An easier fix is to go into about:config in Firefox and change the 
security.enterprise_roots.enabled option from TRUE to FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and import the ca-file of your proxy in your machine. On Debian/Ubuntu

- a pem coded file under /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
- import via "update-ca-certificates"